# How to generate javadoc-style documentation for Scala-only project in sbt?

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have a Scala project under sbt. I'd like to generate a javadoc for it as most of the users of the project API are Java developers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

I assume that you want your docs in JavaDoc format in order to have something familiar to people that are used to java libraries?

There is a project from typesafe called *GenJavaDoc* that might be what you are looking for. It generates docs for a scala library in a format that is very similar to javadoc. It can be integrated into an sbt build.

Akka has a very complete java api, and many of the users of Akka come from the java world, so obviously they have a need for this.

[The project repository](https://github.com/typesafehub/genjavadoc)

[Akka japi docs generated by the tool](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/snapshot/)

[Blog post by Roland Kuhn describing the tool and the rationale](http://typesafe.com/blog/genjavadoc-generate-true-javadoc-for-scala-pr)

Answer (score 5):

```
% sbt doc
```

You'll find the results in `target/scala-version/api` (assuming you're using a simple SBT project that does not have multiple sub-projects).

**Update:**

Experimentation shows that SBT's `doc` command generates docs for *both* the Scala and Java sources in the project.

Comment: i think sbt doc generates scala doc

Comment: There **IS** a difference for the OP who asked about having javadoc-style documentation for **Scala** types => downvoted.

Comment: It's basically nonsensical to ask for Javadoc-style documentation for Scala code. If the two could be equated from that perspective, the languages would be interchangeable.

Comment: The fact that this generate scala doc should be clearly mentioned in the answer. However, SO answers should also aim to address the potential real need of the OP which could be different from exact formulation. Simply because he don't know about scaladoc, the OP could ask for a javadoc style doc meaning html etc...,  and not for the exact javadoc style. I appreciate such answer to my questions, and to others as well => +1